# Android studio- saltear activity

Tags: android-studio, activity

Estoy haciendo una aplicación, más para aprender de los errores que otra cosa, y necesitaba ayuda para lograr esto:

Del `Main activty`, abro `activity2`, y de `activity2` abro un `activity3`, pero no quiero que el usuario pueda volver atrás y entrar a `activty2`, sino que salte hacia el `Main activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas la instrucción :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Pagina1.this, Ayuda.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Añades una actividad a la pila de actividades de Android. Por lo tanto si quieres quitar elementos de la pila, usar `startActivity` sin opciones es justamente lo contrario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para quitar actividades de la pila puedes usar:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Puedes ver mas información en el sitio [oficial de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Clearing)

Answer (score 1):

> Desde Mainactivity, abro activity2, y de activity2 abro un activity3, pero
>   no quiero que el usuario pueda volver atrás y entrar a activty2, sino
>   que salte hacia el Main activity.

Esto sería sencillo de implementar, simplemente has uso del método `finish()` para cerrar la `Activity`  que no deseas mantener.

Cuando abras `activity3` desde `activity2`, finalizas `activity2` mediante `finish()`:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity2.this, activity3.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

De esta forma cuando el usuario cierre `activity3` volvera a `Mainactivty` ya que previamente finalizo `activity2`.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo solucione así: (no se si será la forma correcta pero al menos ahora anda)

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // Añade más funciones si fuese necesario
        Intent intent = new Intent(Pagina1.this, Ayuda.class);  // Invoca al método
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```